# org.awaitility.Awaitility.await() is never triggered

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, polling, callable

I saw this [post](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage) on how to use `org.awaitility.await()`

I have this code:

```
public void bar() {

    await().forever().pollInterval(5, SECONDS).until(foo());
}

private Callable<Boolean> foo() {
    String a= "1";
    return new Callable<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

but when I debug it, i stop with breakpoint on

`await().forever().pollInterval(5, SECONDS).until(foo());`

but my breakpint on `String a= "1";` and `return true;` never stops.

Am i missing something?

I have also tried this, with no print to the screen:

```
public ConfigActivityLog pollForVersionAwaitingJenkins() {
    ConfigActivityLog[] dbConfigChangeWrapper = new ConfigActivityLog[1];
    await().atLeast(1, MINUTES).pollInterval(5, SECONDS).until(foo());
    return dbConfigChangeWrapper[0];
}

private Callable<Boolean> foo() {
    System.out.println("in foo1");
    return new Callable<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("in foo2");
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It works on my side with v `1.7` and `2.0`, maybe it is an issue with your debugger, try to print a message in `foo` and in `call`

Comment: BTW the method name in `2.0` is rather `org.awaitility.Awaitility.await()`

Comment: `a = "1"` is a no-op, a compiler is not required to generate code for it at all. Besides, you tagged your question with Java-8, so you can just pass a lambda expression to `until` without the need for the `foo()` method.

Comment: @Holger my function is larger, I made it simple only for the post here

Comment: Sure, but you have to avoid oversimplifying, to keep the code capable for reproducing the problem and still reproducing it for the same reason.

Comment: When `"in foo1"` is never printed, the most plausible explanation is that `foo()` is never called. When you assume that `pollForVersionAwaitingJenkins()` *is* called, there must be either, an exception before the invocation of `foo()` or the execution stops/hangs before it.

Comment: it was because of an exception not in the main thread. maybe you can help me with that q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285628/debugging-multithreads-in-intellij-how-can-i-see-the-all-thrown-exceptions