# debugging multiThreads in intellij: how can i see the all thrown exceptions?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, testing, intellij-idea

I have a multithreaded code in java.

I debug with intellij. I know how to switch debug contexts between threads.

Nevertheless the console shows only exception thrown for the main thread.

How can i see the exceptions thrown from any thread?

[image]

[image]

basically when I run integration test with an Executor, some exception is thrown from secondary thread.

But nothing is printed to the debug-console.

Actually the the code flies and never reach to the try catch i have.

It's like I cannot step-next after the code that throws an exception

```
try {
    while (true) {
        logger.debug("New thread. polling on DB, polling on deployment service");

        ConfigAction configAction = configActionFactory.get(ConfigActionsEnum.PushToDeployment);

        while (configAction != null) {
            configAction = configAction.execute() ? configAction.nextActivity() : null;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.error("DeploymentContextListener run failed", e);
}
```

whereas when I run with the main thread, the **same** code I see the exception:

```
public void run() {

    try {
        while (true) {
            logger.debug("New thread. polling on DB, polling on deployment service");

            ConfigAction configAction = configActionFactory.get(ConfigActionsEnum.PushToDeployment);

            while (configAction != null) {
                configAction = configAction.execute() ? configAction.nextActivity() : null;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("DeploymentContextListener run failed", e);
    }
```

it is written in one of the try-catch i have

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error("failed to get from DB: getLatestConfigVersionWaitingForDeploy", ex);
}
```

Comment: I use Eclipse, but I would be surprised if IntelliJ doesn’t have similar options, e.g. to stop on every thrown exception, otherwise, setting a breakpoint in every `Throwable` constructor should enforce stopping for most exceptions.

Comment: I put breakpoint in every try-catch and it didn't stop there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that i used:

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(() -> { }
```

from what I have read:

invokeAll - call “future.get()”. Wait for all threads to finish.

Submit -> attach the errors to Future objects, not the the std-error

Execute -> the errors are thrown to the std-error